# How to write where clause with joining 2 tables, having ORs in the clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables `A_ORDERS` and `A_ORDERS_LOG`. Columns of interest in table `A_ORDERS` are `PEN` and `SKL`, and Columns in table `A_ORDERS_LOG` that are of interest are `Status1` and `Status2` as well as `DATE` (just for ordering my result). `PEN` is unique.

This is what I have

```
select
 l.pen,status1,status2,date,a.skl 

from A_ORDERS_LOG l

join A_ORDERS a on l.PEN=a.PEN 

where a.skl='XY'

and status1='75' or status1='13'

and status2='13' or status2='11'

order by l.id,l.date;
```

I get all the rows for all the other skl's there are in the table `A_ORDERS`, but I only want rows regarding `skl=XY` from `A_ORDERS`. The thing is that PENs travel through different status and I want all the rows for each `PEN` where it went through possible status from 75 to 13 and then from 13 to 11.

When I put it like this I get what I want.

```
and (status1='75' or status1='13')
and (status2='13' or status2='11');
```

Why is that?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That's because AND has preference over OR, check this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions001.htm#i1034834

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when there are multiple operators, operator precedence determines the sequence of operations. The order of execution can significantly affect the resulting value.
Operator AND Is having higher precedence over OR operator.
You want OR (Status 1 and status 2 ) to be considered first.So, when you write them in parenthesis () OR expression gets evaluated first rather than AND. Absence of parentheses will lead to the execution of AND expression.

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```sql
select l.pen,
       status1,
       status2,
       date,
       a.skl 
from   A_ORDERS_LOG l
       join A_ORDERS a
       on l.PEN=a.PEN 
where  a.skl='XY'
and    status1='75'
or     status1='13'
and    status2='13'
or     status2='11'
order by l.id,l.date;
```

Then `AND` has a [higher operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions001.htm#i1034834) than `OR` so your query is interpreted as:

```sql
where  ( a.skl='XY'   and status1='75' )
or     ( status1='13' and status2='13' )
or     status2='11'
```

What you want is to use brackets to enforce the precedence you require:

```sql
where  a.skl='XY'
and    ( status1='75' or status1='13' )
and    ( status2='13' or status2='11' )
```

or you could use `IN` (and get rid of the `OR`s):

```sql
where  a.skl='XY'
and    status1 IN ( '75', '13' )
and    status2 IN ( '13', '11' )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the operator precedence. It's like in math. In

```
2 + 3 * 4 + 5
```

`*` has precedence over `+`, i.e. the above expression is equivalent to

```
2 + (3 * 4) + 5
```

If you want to perform the addition first, you must use braces

```
(2 + 3) * (4 + 5)
```

In SQL `AND` has precedence over `OR`. Therefore

```
a.skl='XY' AND status1='75' OR status1='13' AND status2='13' OR status2='11'
```

is equivalent to

```
(a.skl='XY' AND status1='75') OR (status1='13' AND status2='13') OR status2='11'
```

You want

```
a.skl='XY' AND (status1='75' OR status1='13') AND (status2='13' OR status2='11')
```

and must therefore change the precedence with braces. Braces always have the highest precedence.

See: [Operator precedence rules](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E49933_01/server.770/es_eql/src/ceql_expr_precedence_rules.html) (Oracle Docs).